# Typedef doesn't work in included file

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define internal static
#define local_persist static
#define global_variable static

#define Pi32 3.14159265359f

typedef int8_t int8;
typedef int16_t int16;
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef int64_t int64;
typedef int32 bool32;

typedef uint8_t uint8;
typedef uint16_t uint16;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef uint64_t uint64;

typedef float real32;
typedef double real64;

#include "someheader.h"
// etc
```

And in the someheader.h file I have:

```
struct game_sound_output_buffer
{
    int16* Samples;
    int SampleCount;
    int SamplesPerSecond;
};
```

I am using Visual Studio and I get these errors on the line with the int16* variable:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Why does this happen? I typedefed before including the header file.
And the weirder thing, it works fine if I compile from the command line

```
cl -FC -Zi file.cpp user32.lib Gdi32.lib
```

Comment: Are the `typedef`s defined in another header file? If so, that header file should be included ere the types be used.

Comment: The typedefs are in the .cpp file. (the first one in the post)

Comment: @devil0150 [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen. Probably there's a problem with include guards or such. Anyway `someheader.h` should include the typdef declarations from your header file, not vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declaring the typedefs in one file and then including another file after them does not add those typedefs into that other file.  All including a file does is it copy and paste the code from the file into the file doing the including.  The original file still does not know about those types so when the compiler gets to it there will be an error.

What you need to do is include the file that has the typedefs in it in the file that is using them

**mytypes.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define internal static
#define local_persist static
#define global_variable static

#define Pi32 3.14159265359f

typedef int8_t int8;
typedef int16_t int16;
//...
```

**header file that uses the types**

```
#include "mytypes.h" // oh now I see all of those types and I can use them
struct game_sound_output_buffer
{
    int16* Samples;
    int SampleCount;
    int SamplesPerSecond;
};
```

Comment: The typedefs should be known in the included file if they're declared before it is included.As you said, like copy and paste, if the typedef is declared before the struct, it should work. And if that's the problem, it shouldn't compile in command line either.

Comment: @devil0150 Yes.  But if you have a situation where you have a source file that includes your header but it doesn't have the types then you will get an error.  A header file should include/forward declare all types it is using so it can stand alone and be included in any order in source files.

Comment: I put all the defines and typedefs in a separate file and included it in both the header and the source. It works fine. But I still don't get why the previous code worked in the command line and not in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `typedef`s in their own header, something like `someotherheader.h`, and then include that at the top of `someheader.h`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In your example you used the type `int16` but you did only define `int16_t`!</strike>

Anyway, It is good practive to include the header file that supplies the types in the file that uses the types, so you should put the definitions in their own file and include that in someheader.h.

Comment: _"In your example you used the type `int16` but you did only define `int16_t`!"_ Not true: `typedef int16_t int16;` Line 10 of the 1st codeblock.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but the rest of the advice applies.